# Print code behind function return value in aspx page

Tags: asp.net, function, inline, code-behind, css

I'm sure this is trivial, but why isn't the Windows Authentication user printing in my ASP.NET page inline?

Code behind function:

```
public string GetCurrentUserWindowsLogin()
{
    string windowsLogin = Page.User.Identity.Name;
    int hasDomain = windowsLogin.IndexOf(@"\");
    if (hasDomain > 0)
    {
        windowsLogin = windowsLogin.Remove(0, hasDomain + 1);
    }
    return windowsLogin;
}
```

Inline code:

```
<div class="loginDisplay">[ <%#GetCurrentUserWindowsLogin() %> ]</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<%#... %>` is used for [Binding Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178366.aspx) like `Eval` and `Bind`.

So if you call `Page.DataBind()` in `page_load` it should work.

Another way that should work is to use [code render blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6xeyd4z.aspx) which run normal code:

`<% GetCurrentUserWindowsLogin() %>`

or the [`<%= %>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dwsdcf5%28VS.71%29.aspx) construct used for small chunks of information:

`<%= GetCurrentUserWindowsLogin() %>`

Comment: after a high search i found major reason for show Eval value is Page.DataBind().

Answer (score 0):

Just a follow up on the above answer, the <%= is like response.write.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/6dwsdcf5(v=vs.100).aspx