# Return certain value from SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to use a function to check if the email exists, and I want to return both the user's name and email. How can I do that and what should I do with my existing code? And how can I pass the username and email to the aspx page?

```
public static string searchEmail(string email)
{
    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    {
        conn.Open();

        bool exists = false;

        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Member where email = @email", conn))
        {
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);
            exists = (int)comm.ExecuteScalar() > 0;
        }

        if (exists)
        {
            return "Password has been reset, please check your email box!";
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not query all of the data you want instead of a `COUNT` and just check for a row using `ExecuteReader` and `Read()`?

Comment: Stored procedures are marvelous.

Comment: I would agree with @Adam. this would be better in a stored procedure. You also should take a look at this article. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: so you guys want to create a stored procedure just to return the userName ? ....

Comment: @dzomba Yes in fact I would suggest just that. I do not like having queries in the application, even in the data layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this ...

```
public static Tuple<string,string> searchEmail(string email)
{
    string userName = "";
    connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    {
        conn.Open();              

        using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select UserName from Member where email = @email", conn))
        {
            SqlDataReader reader;
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", email);

            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
              while (reader.Read())
              {                                
                 userName = reader.GetString(0);
              }
            }
        }          
    }
     conn.Close();
     return new Tuple<string,string>(email,userName);
}
```

Comment: How can i capture the passed value on the aspx page?

Comment: i don't understand your question... what do you mean ?

Comment: As in how can i display the username on the aspx page?

Comment: aspx page using MVC ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398174/print-code-behind-function-return-value-in-aspx-page

Comment: What i just want to do is to return either null or both the username and pass so that i can display a text label of showing email not found or it will send an email to the user with the password

Comment: I've edited the answer above, is this to right way to return email, username and password?

Comment: no. Tuple does not have 3 elements !

Comment: Just dynamically set the label text from the codebehind. You don't need to pass it to the .aspx code to do that.

Comment: @Adam Because i want to do send mail function with username, email password in the code behind, how can i do that easily?

Comment: man you asked same question some time ago....
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31379703/return-a-value-from-sql

Comment: So store it in the class. Add some ` get; set; }` accessors or something along those lines. There is NO reason you should need to pass that information from codebehind to the markup

Comment: @dzomba And what do you know. Setting label text dynamically is what they said too. This guy is trying to play me.

Comment: Im not trying to play you guys, im very poor in coding thats why im confused too.

Comment: my question then... why do you code ? :D

Comment: Because its my sch assignment :(

Comment: check you other question.. you have the answer in there !

Comment: Yes, i know that thing but its hard to explain what i really want to do. i try to explain again, 1. I want to check if the email exist in the Member table. 2. If yes, i want to return username, email and password to the code behind the aspx page so that i can use them to send a mail to the particular user.

What will be the easiest and straightforward to do it?

Comment: Well have you created a method that sends the mail ?